azure function with dotnet-isolated mode returns 404 with no job functions found error as message
Expected Behavior
Deploy into Azure Portal a dotnet-isolated function with a simple http trigger and  consume it with curl or any http client
Current Behavior
I'm getting 404 error at the moment to invoke the HttpTrigger after the deployment into azure portal

I'm using the latest versions:

dotnet 8
net 8
AzureFunctionsVersion v4
terraform azurerm_windows_function_app
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"

Note:

It works when code is executed using Visual Studio  2022

It works with visual studio 2022 and windows 10



Source code
The source code
https://github.com/jrichardsz/azure-functions-terraform-csharp-samples/tree/v1.0.1-snapshot/http-dotnet-isolated
HttpTriggerSimple.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp
{
    public static class HttpTriggerSimple
    {
        [Function(nameof(HttpTriggerSimple))]
        public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("FunctionApp.HttpTriggerSimple");
            logger.LogInformation("Message logged");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            response.Headers.Add("Date", "Mon, 18 Jul 2016 16:06:00 GMT");
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Hello world!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}

csproj
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <SdkVersion>1.17.2</SdkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Program.cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Configuration;

namespace FunctionApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    s.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                    s.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
                    s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                            == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
                        if (toRemove is not null)
                        {
                            options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
                        }
                    });
                })
                .Build();
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}

This code is from official docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples/FunctionApp



Azure deploy
I deployed using terraform scripts. It ends with success but the endpoint is returning 404
Terraform first zip the src folder (source code) and then execute this:
az functionapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name} --name ${azurerm_windows_function_app.azure_function.name} --src ${data.archive_file.file_function_app.output_path} --build-remote true

curl https://az-function-foobarbaz-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerSimple -v


The resources are well deployed

Zip deployment works and files exist in azure

I see these errors



The Dashboard setting is no longer supported. See https://aka.ms
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:dotnet-
Unable to update the debug sentinel file.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException


Attempts

No matter what I apply, the errors are the same in Azure Portal
I tried a lot of stackoverflow, github and official docs about 404 and isolated mode but no one works

Deployed Isolated Function App returns 404
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/26252
Azure function failing to start
Azure Isolated Function App (.net 8) won't start
Azure Function fails to start when in cloud
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2075
New deployed azure function returns 404 Not Found error
All Azure Functions returning 404 after upgrading to v4 runtime
Azure function returns 404
.net 6 azure function time trigger 404 not found error
Why am I getting a 404 when I run my Azure Function locally?
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-azure-functions-http-trigger-404-error/ba-p/3766817
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2029
.Net8 Azure Functions not detected
Azure Function - Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated
Azure function local development in VS cannot find function
No job functions found, migrating to .net 8 isolated worker process
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT is set to false explicitly by Azure Cli




Questions

Why is failing in azure portal when it works in localhost?
How can I get more logs?


Are you using zip deploy or terraform script for the function app deployment?

I'm using  zip_deploy with azure-functions-core-tools . I will update the question

Please check the solution which I posted below.


azure function with dotnet-isolated mode returns 404 with no job functions found error as message

The Error No job function indicates function not properly running. you can delete the function and re-deploy the function into azure portal.

Make sure to Switch ON the basic authentication Configuration>>general settings>>ON  like below:



I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack .NET 8.0 isolated.
I have used function code which you provided runs successfully in local. check below:

public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger("Function1");
        logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        logger.LogInformation("Message logged");

        var response = req.CreateResponse();
        response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        await response.WriteStringAsync("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }
}

Check the packages which provided below:
.cs proj:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />



I have created function app with consumption plan and published the function into azure portal successfully.



I have tried with curl zip deployment also to deploy the function by follow this DOC




The function ran in azure portal by invoke the Http function URL.  check below:


Output:

